# How to convert a textview to Imageview

Tags: android

I am trying to get a Imageview from textview. I tried many methods but not able to set that textview on Imageview as image.

I tried following method:

```
TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textview);
tv.buildDrawingCache();
ImageView img = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageview);
img.setImageBitmap(tv.getDrawingCache());
```

but i am not still able to show that textview on Imageview. Can someone help me that how can i set textview as image on that imageview?

Comment: Not sure if I guess correct but maybe image button will help in what You try to achive?

Comment: No how can i do that?

Comment: Why do you need to get textView as bitmap? To show text on imageView? Imagebutton offers this out of the box.

Comment: Thanx for the suggestion i will try to implement that

Answer (score 0):

Try this, if it maya help you

```
yourTextView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
yourTextView.buildDrawingCache();
yourImageview.setImageBitmap(tv1.getDrawingCache());
```

Comment: I tried this also i am not able to save that on imageview

Comment: With this i am not able to set that textview on imageview

Answer (score 0):

call

```
tv.buildDrawingCache(true);

Bitmap b = tv.getDrawingCache(true).copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, false);
tv.destroyDrawingCache();

img.setImageBitmap(b);
```

Comment: There is not any effect on imageview. Imageview is still blank

Comment: Try to print bitmap..did u get null as bitmap